# Error al cargar parámetros a un Report Viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

Tengo un reporte que, para generarlo en el reportviewer, necesita recibir un parámetro. Este parametro se debe escribir en un textbox (`id="documento"`), el reporte se genera pero en blanco.

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
ReportDataSource report = new ReportDataSource();    
string dni = documento.Text.ToString();
                    ReportViewer1.Reset();
                    ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[1];
                    parameters[0] = new ReportParameter(dni);

                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "AsistenciaPersonal.rptHorariosPersonal.rdlc";
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameters);
                    report.Name = "HorariosPersonal";
                    report.Value = new HorarioDocentesDataSet.buscaHorarioDocenteDataTable();
                    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(report);
```

Los datos del datatable son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El reporte se genera, pero todo en blanco, por favor alguien que me ayude?

Answer (score 0):

El error podría estar en:

```
parameters[0] = new ReportParameter(dni);
```

ya que debes de especificar el nombre tu parametro:`ReportParameter("nombre_parametro","valor_del_parametro");`, dependiendo con que nombre esta tu variable en el reporte deberia de quedar asi:

```
parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("dni",dni);
```

Al final tambien te faltaria una linea de codigo:

```
ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero cuando agrego parameters[0] = new ReportParameter("dni",dni); me sale ERROR: Se ha intentado establecer un parámetro de informe '@dni', que no está definido en este informe. :(

Comment: Pues tienes que definirlo, o quiza esta con otro nombre, al lado izquierdo donde donde aparecen los componentes, fijate que este definido.